# Hide text in officer using prop argument

Tags: r, officer

I have 5 footnotes that I want to use in one place, and I want to make the footnotes print to the document with the "hidden" font feature. Instead of saying "1-2345" I want it to say "1-5". I imagine this is possible with the prop argument, but I have not seen anywhere how I can do this to hide it.

```
fp_par_footnote <- fp_par(line_spacing = 1, word_style = "Compact")
fp_text_refnote <- fp_text_lite(vertical.align = "superscript")

footnotes_blocklist <- block_list(
  fpar(ftext("Footnote 1"), fp_p = fp_par_footnote), 
  fpar(ftext("Footnote 2"), fp_p = fp_par_footnote),
  fpar(ftext("Footnote 3"), fp_p = fp_par_footnote),
  fpar(ftext("Footnote 4"), fp_p = fp_par_footnote),
  fpar(ftext("Footnote 5"), fp_p = fp_par_footnote),


fpar(
    ftext("Example text."),
    run_footnote(x = footnotes_blocklist[1], prop = fp_text_refnote),
    ftext("-", prop = fp_text_refnote),
    run_footnote(x = footnotes_blocklist[2], prop = fp_text_refnote),
    run_footnote(x = footnotes_blocklist[3], prop = fp_text_refnote),
    run_footnote(x = footnotes_blocklist[4], prop = fp_text_refnote),
    run_footnote(x = footnotes_blocklist[5], prop = fp_text_refnote))
```